# Working between classes Objective C

Tags: objective-c, variables

I have a basic question about working with classes in objective-c and maybe just programming in general. I would like to use a variable declared in my class `Signup.h` in another class, `Exittext.m`. When I include `"Signup.h"`  in my .m file and try to use the variable, it doesn't know what it is. Is this because they are private? Is there a way to do this or can I  only use variables declared in that particular class?

```
@interface SignupView : UIViewController
 NSMutableArray *textfields;

}

@implementation Exittextfields

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ 

       [textfields resignFirstResponder];

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Read about properties.

Comment: private? Whats that in obj-c?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya create an iVar in a class extension in the implementation file. Don't write accessors for them. Private. It's methods that can't be private. Variables can be.

Comment: @Abizern: Yeah this I know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In traditional OO programming, accessing a variable in another class involves manually writing getter and accessor methods to expose/modify a "private" variable. In Objective-C, properties (instance variables declared with `@property`) takes care of generating those getters and setters automatically.

Check out [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial) by Ray Wenderlich.

So in your case, you'll need to declare the mutable array you want to be accessed by other classes in the .h file as a property.

Example:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;`

Now when a new instance of `Signup` is called, the array `myArray` can be properly accessed using either a traditional getter method or dot syntax.

Example:

```
Signup *sign = [[Signup alloc] init];
[sign myArray];
//OR
sign.myArray;
```

Comment: It stopped complaining. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would argue that in _traditional_ OO programming, objects collaborate by sending messages to each other (or themselves), rather than by accessing each other's state via accessor and mutator methods.